# Insert a new record (asp .net & c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a newbie to asp .net and c# world. I'm trying to insert a very new record into a simple task manager database table, tasks (name, description, priority, start_date, end_date)

Here is my Task.cs and add.aspx code:
http://pastie.org/691005

When I submit the form, it just redirect me back to the Default.aspx page. Is there anyway to debug the inside the Insert method of Task.cs? How can I output the sql query from within the Task.cs file? I'm using Microsoft SQL express.

Thank you

Comment: If you're using the integrated web server, you can set breakpoints, etc within your code to isolate the problem.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You're not displaying any data anywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think your `INSERT` statement's syntax is wrong.

You have:

```
INSERT INTO Tablename Field1=Value1, Field2=Value2...
```

The correct syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO Tablename (Field1, Field2... ) VALUES ( Value1, Value2... )
```

The syntax you're using works for an `UPDATE` statement, as in

```
UPDATE Tablename SET field1=value1, field2=value2...
    WHERE some-key-fieldname=some-key-value
```

Comment: Hmmm... you've just given me an idea for a good Community Wiki question about why the syntax difference between INSERT and UPDATE statements. But first a Google search...

Comment: Because you can `INSERT` a `SELECT` query, but you can't `UPDATE` from a `SELECT` query.

Comment: Thank you Bob for your suggestion. I spotted my mistake. Here is the updated working version if anyone later interested: http://www.pastie.org/691085

Taking out the OnInserted helped me seeing the error page so it won't redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Try taking out the `OnInserted` handler.