# Why do SQL INSERT and UPDATE Statements have Different Syntaxes?

Tags: sql

While contemplating [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704326/insert-a-new-record-asp-net-c) about a SQL `INSERT` statement, it occurred to me that the distinction in syntax between the two statements is largely artificial. That is, why can't we do:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable SET Field1=Value1, Field2=Value2, ...
```

or

```
UPDATE MyTable ( Field1, Field2 ...) VALUES ( Value1, Value2, ... ) 
    WHERE some-key = some-value
```

Perhaps I'm missing something critical. But for those of us who have had to concatenate our SQL statements in the past, having comparable syntax for an `INSERT` and an `UPDATE` statement would have saved a significant amount of coding.

Comment: Not really a question =P

Comment: Sorry, but this is a discussion-type question and does not really fit the intent of the site.

Comment: @ajdams -- I wasn't sure, but I was sure that if it could be asked at all, it should be part of the Wiki

Comment: In MySQL you can do INSERT ... SET ...

Comment: @ajdams and @jkndrkn - after further consideration, I respectfully disagree with your assertions. As OP, I was looking for a definite response rather than a debate, and @Alex Miller's response indicates there is just such a response.

Comment: @jkndrkn: It depends. Often, questions like this have well defined answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're serving different grammatical functions.  In an update you are specifying a filter that chooses a set of rows to which you will apply an update.  And of course that syntax is shared with a SELECT query for the same purpose.

In an INSERT you are not choosing any rows, you are generating a new row which requires specifying a set of values.

In an UPDATE, the LHS=RHS stuff is specifying an expression which yields true or false (or maybe null :) and in an INSERT, the VALUES clause is about assignment of value.  So while they are superficially similar, they are semantically quite different, imho.  Although I have written a SQL parser, so that may influence my views. :)

Answer (score 5):

SQL Server 2008 has introduced UPSERT functionality via the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) command.  This is the logical equivalent of

```
IF FOUND THEN
 UPDATE
ELSE
 INSERT
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is so that you may make an insert statement without being explicit about the values.  If you are putting a value in every single column in the table you can write:

insert into my_table values ("value1", 2);

instead of:

insert into my_table (column1, column2) values ("value1", 2);

When importing and exporting entire (large) databases, this is invaluable for cutting down file size and processing time.  Nowadays, with binary snapshots and the like, it may be "less invaluable" :-)